# Accidentally moved /bin, /boot, /dev and /etc folders

Tags: centos7, boot, dev, bin

So as I was installing a new website, I incorrectly entered:

```
mv wordpress /* .
```

The space between "wordress" and "/*" was unitentional.

Folders affected were:
/bin
/boot
/dev
/etc

I Ctrl + C'd quit before it got any further forward. Since then I moved the folders back but have noticed that I cannot SSH or FTP any new connections. I am still connected on Terminal and obviously don't want to disconnect until I can fix this issue.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why were you installing a new website with root privileges? Usually you run websites as some user and should make site-specific installations using the permissions of that user account alone. Now that the harm was already done, restore your server from the latest backup instead of trying to glue it back together.

Comment: Cheers. very useful....

Server now fixed (not glued together).   